# How are functions $F: X \to Y^n$ constructed from $n$ functions $f_i: X \to Y$

Tags: functions

Given $n$ functions 
$$f_i : X \to Y$$
one can construct
$$F^\prime: X^n \to Y^n$$
by taking a product over them. What about if I want to construct a function
$$F: X \to Y^n$$
what mathematical operation achieves this?

Example in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$f_0(x) = x$$
$$f_1(x) = x^2$$
$$F(x) = (x, x^2)$$
It is not a product, because a product would be
$$F^\prime(x, y) = (x, y^2)$$
but I do not know what it is.

Comment: What prevents you from defining $F(x)=(f_0(x),f_1(x),\dots,f_{n-1}(x))$?

Comment: Nothing :). Perhaps I worded the question poorly. My question is, what is this called. if F' is constructed via product, what is F constructed via? Fork? Your definition for example. I hope my I cleared up my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental property of product sets is

> if $X,Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n$ are sets and $f_i\colon X\to Y_i$ ($i=1,2,\dots,n$) are maps, then there exists a unique map $F\colon X\to Y_1\times Y_2\times\dots\times Y_n$ such that $\pi_i\circ F=f_i$, where $\pi_i\colon Y_1\times Y_2\times\dots\times Y_n\to Y_i$ is the projection map (that selects the $i$-th coordinate).

Of course the map $F$ is defined by $F(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),\dots,f_n(x))$.

In your case, $Y_1=Y_2=\dots=Y_n=Y$.

How's it called? It may be called the *product map*, why not?

Note that this is much more natural to construct than your $F'$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I too agree that F' is more natural. So would it be OK to call F, the product, and F', the product map? I am asking because I hear 'product' in many places for F (in Computer Science). Either way, you answered my question, so I am accepting the answer.